# How to create a sequence of events (column values) per some other column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark data frame as shown below -

```
val myDF = Seq(
(1,"A",100,0,0),
(1,"E",200,0,0),
(1,"",300,1,49),
(2,"A",200,0,0),
(2,"C",300,0,0),
(2,"D",100,0,0)
).toDF("visitor","channel","timestamp","purchase_flag","amount")


scala> myDF.show
+-------+-------+---------+-------------+------+
|visitor|channel|timestamp|purchase_flag|amount|
+-------+-------+---------+-------------+------+
|      1|      A|      100|            0|     0|
|      1|      E|      200|            0|     0|
|      1|       |      300|            1|    49|
|      2|      A|      200|            0|     0|
|      2|      C|      300|            0|     0|
|      2|      D|      100|            0|     0|
+-------+-------+---------+-------------+------+
```

I would like to create Sequence dataframe for every visitor from `myDF` that traces a visitor's path to purchase ordered by `timestamp` dimension.
The output dataframe should look like below(`->` can be any delimiter) -

```
+-------+---------------------+
|visitor|channel sequence     |
+-------+---------------------+
|      1| A->E->purchase      |
|      2| D->A->C->no_purchase|
+-------+---------------------+
```

To make things clear, visitor `2` has been exposed to channel `D`, then `A` and then `C`; and he does not make a purchase. 
Hence the sequence is to be formed as `D->A-C->no_purchase`.

**NOTE:** Whenever a purchase happens, channel value goes `blank` and `purchase_flag` is set to 1.

I want to do this using a `Scala UDF` in Spark so that I re-apply the method on other datasets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how it is done using `udf` function

```
val myDF = Seq(
  (1,"A",100,0,0),
  (1,"E",200,0,0),
  (1,"",300,1,49),
  (2,"A",200,0,0),
  (2,"C",300,0,0),
  (2,"D",100,0,0)
).toDF("visitor","channel","timestamp","purchase_flag","amount")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def sequenceUdf = udf((struct: Seq[Row], purchased: Seq[Int])=> struct.map(row => (row.getAs[String]("channel"), row.getAs[Int]("timestamp"))).sortBy(_._2).map(_._1).filterNot(_ == "").mkString("->")+{if(purchased.contains(1)) "->purchase" else "->no_purchase"})

myDF.groupBy("visitor").agg(collect_list(struct("channel", "timestamp")).as("struct"), collect_list("purchase_flag").as("purchased"))
  .select(col("visitor"), sequenceUdf(col("struct"), col("purchased")).as("channel sequence"))
  .show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+-------+--------------------+
|visitor|channel sequence    |
+-------+--------------------+
|1      |A->E->purchase      |
|2      |D->A->C->no_purchase|
+-------+--------------------+
```

You can make it as much generic as you can . this is just a demo on how you should proceed